# WoL Mac from power-off mode?

Tags: mac, wake-on-lan

is there a way to wake the Mac out of a complete power off? I normally don't use the sleep mode,but I also want to wake the Mac sometimes for various reasons (it's a part of my entertainment system).

Any way I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, not with "standard Macs".

The feature you are looking for is called LOM (Lights Out Management). It enables you to start a machine even if it's powered off.

Apple sold [Xserve servers that supported LOM](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA24506?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), but with regular Macs it's not possible.

Comment: Thank you! I heard that from various sources and just wanted to make sure